# How could authentication work across microservices?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt, microservices

I have two separate Node.js services.

Service `A` is responsible for authenticating users.  If a user successfully logs in, the user is redirected to Service `B` (hosted on a **subdomain** of the domain Service `A` is hosted on).

I am using [JWT](https://jwt.io/) for authentication.

**Question:** How can Service `B` be aware if a user is or is not authenticated?

I imagine one way that Service `B` could be aware if they are or aren't authenticated is by asking Service `A` to check the JWT on each  Request to Service `B`. But how is Service `A` supposed to send the JWT to the client when the client is going to be redirected to a new origin?

Is it safe to do something like:

```
window.location.href = 'https://b.example.com?jwt=tokenhere'
```

I don't believe storing the JWT on `localStorage` since it does not allow cross origin access.

Comment: Why would microservices need to be cross origin? We run a website implemented not only accross multiple services but multiple programming languages. We don't generally use CORS except when we need to cross the http/https boundary. Use an API/service gateway. They don't need to be complicated beasts. We simply use Nginx. I used to use Apache on a previous project

Comment: @slebetman, Thank you for your response.  The way I am thinking about this is that some domain `example.com` allows users to log in.  Once logged in, the user is redirected to a subdomain matching the company name of the user, `companyname.example.com`.  I have seen various SaaS apps do something similar, and I'm curious to know how this could be done with microservices.     Is the website you are referring to a Saas app?

Comment: @slebetman, Also, if you have any resources that you recommend on implementing microservices in Node.js, I've love if you shared them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another bit of detail that the others haven't touched on:

If your clients are using web browsers, and if you want the user to be authenticated with both services without having to re-login (single sign-on)

E.g. if your domain is example.com, service A is at example.com and service B is at b.example.com.

1. Send login request to authentication service at example.com
2. Auth service verifies credentials and if they match, sends a cookie back to client with domain set to `example.com`
3. Client receives and stores cookie
4. On all future requests the browser will send the cookie to service A and service B
5. In service A and service B verify the  JWT received in the cookie (see other peoples answers)

This method ONLY works when you're running on same root domain and your authentication service MUST be on the root domain. If you have a different setup I would recommend looking at a single sign-on product (e.g. [Central Authentication Service](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas))

Comment: Thanks, I totally forgot that cookies can be accessible across root and subdomains.  This, in my opinion, is the simplest answer to my question.  However, I will be learning about about microservice architectures in general to see if there is a way to achieve the same subdomain result with all microservices on the same origin using an API/service gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Use RSA for your JWT generation. You can make the public key available to all other microservices. If the client uses CORS to talk to different services directly (vs. an API gateway), pack the JWT in the Authorization header as usual.

Answer (score 2):

If your servers share a secret key you can encrypt and decrypt the token on any server. Inside the token you can write who the user is and what permissions he has. Whenever the user wants to perform some restricted action you decrypt the token and check wheter he has permission to do what he wants. Don't forget to give the token a time to live so it won't last forever.

I'm not a js guru so I won't paste code but you should be able to find an example [here](https://coderead.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/securing-node-js-restful-services-with-jwt-tokens/)